# Problem The connection has timed out while connecting to server

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I use data factpry to copy data from sftp to Mysql database,when i try to connect to Mysql,i got this error ERROR [08001] [Microsoft][MySQL] (1004) The connection has timed out while connecting to server: 127.0.0.1 at port: 3306.how can i resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your MySQL Server is on localhost, the issue is with the "Outbound IP" list in MySQL. As your Server is on localhost, make sure you must be using [Self Hosted Integration Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory) and add the IP Addresses used by ADF to the "Outbound IP" list of MySQL Server.

Comment: how can i add the ip addresses to the Outbound IP in Mysql,i used PHPMYADMIN,My sql in app